# applescript launched from terminal but not from php

Tags: php, terminal, applescript

I have an applescript which writes a log file.
It works perfectly if launched from the terminal, but i need to launch it from a php script.
For achieving this I use the *exec* function of php but nothing happens.

The applescript is owned by the user "administrator"
If from php's exec i launch "whoami" I get back "administrator" so I guess it's not a problem of permission.(the applescript has also execution permission on it)

The applescript works both in  this ways:

administrator$ ./myApplescript.app

administrator$ osascript myApplescript.app

If I try to run the very same commands inside php nothing happens.

Someone faced something similar?
Thanks in advance!
Best regards

P.S.
The webserver is MAMP on mac Os x

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<?php
    exec('osascript path/to/script/myApplescript.app');
?>
```

make sure that the path you call is actually correct and that the webserver has access to this file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a user is logged in on the Mac you're running the php from too or else it won't work properly.